# how to set orientation to chrome custom tab in android?

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

i have given the fix orientation to my app as a portrait.i am using chrome custom tab to open another site, however this property can not be set to chrome custom tab to remain portrait. it change its orientations.
in manifest i have set activity like

```
<activity
        android:name=".uicontent.carrental.ZoomCarDrawerActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:noHistory="false"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

thank you.

Comment: Similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231103/lock-orientation-for-custom-tabs

Comment: okay thank you.. helpful.

Comment: It saves much time for me with android:launchMode="singleTask" for the activity customtabs