# Lock orientation in TWA

Tags: progressive-web-apps, chrome-custom-tabs, trusted-web-activity

I followed this [article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/using-twa) to make a TWA from a PWA. Everything is fine and the app feels like the PWA, but what I can't achieve is to lock the orientation to landscape.

The manifest of the PWA has this:

`"orientation": "landscape",
 "display" : "standalone"`

So if you add it to the homescreen from Google chorme it works as intended.

I tried setting the `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` in the manifest file and like this starts the app on landscape but it doesn't lock it.

Anyone has tried locking it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“Custom Tabs does not currently provide an API that allows the developer to lock the orientation.”:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38700267/887595

You could try the “Orientation Lock” method using media queries:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/orientation-lock/

Comment: Oh, thank you. Do you know if its a feature that would be added in the future?

Comment: Did you succeed ? i could'nt.