# How to set only portrait mode for TWA(trusted web activity)?

Tags: android, portrait

I want my trusted web activity to support only portrait mode, but as TWA is running in chrome, orientation configuration in manifest.xml will not work.

I have already tried this code, but it does not affect anything.

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

what will be the solution? I have no java code in application and cannot add some orientation changes programmatically.

Comment: is there android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.LauncherActivity
activity  in your manifest file?

Comment: yes, android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.LauncherActivity" i have this activity

Comment: Ok then you want to change orientation right ?

Comment: i want app to be only in portrait mode

Comment: Add this in your manifest

<activity
            android:name="android.support.customtabs.trusted.LauncherActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

Comment: yes, and it still lets app in landscape mode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lock orientation in TWA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54747441/lock-orientation-in-twa)